# How to share image and text both in facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, share

I can share image and text in Facebook messenger but not in Facebook. How to do that? I am using the following code.

```
  Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE); 
    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");         
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); 
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body text of the new status"); 
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

Comment: Do you get any error ? Please post some more code. From where you are getting image ?

Comment: I am getting the image from my sdcard like "/sdcard/OnItsOwn/sample.jpg"

Comment: This is not the proper way to get the image and share on facebook.

Comment: But i am able to share only the image in facebook through intent but not the text. I would be really greatfull if u can please tell me how i can share both using android's shareintent

Comment: Try out by setting the type as text `sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook does not currently support:

- `EXTRA_TEXT` besides URLs
- `EXTRA_STREAM` from external sources (only local files)

Until Facebook supports those features, you are limited to only local images without any text.

Comment: Even  I cannot able to share both URL(**text/plain**) and Image(**image/jpeg**).

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below :

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                "/OnItsOwn/";

File dir = new File(file_path);
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "sample.jpg");
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);

fOut.flush();
fOut.close();

// Share
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body text of the new status");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code. It is just showing the image but the given text is not appearing in the facebook's text field. But this code works fine in other social media like whattsApp, twitter and others. My issue is only with facebook.

Comment: @Srikara I'm also facing exactly same issue.